# `import()` type annotations are forbidden

Tags: typescript, types, import, typescript-eslint, xstate

I am using XState on the backend and per the XState docs, I added type annotation to my state machine's config:

```
export const machine = createMachine(
    {
      tsTypes: {} as import("./testMachine.server.typegen").Typegen0,
    ...,
    }
```

However, the type cast is throwing this error:

```
`import()` type annotations are forbidden.eslint@typescript-eslint/consistent-type-imports
interface Typegen0
```

I looked into dynamic imports, but that doesn't seem to fix the issue:

```
const dynamicImport = async() => await import("./testMachine.server.typegen")
```

This is from my eslint.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it is just a linting error. Your eslint config expects a certain way of importing types. I would assume the type inference and your code still works.

You can disable the linting error by putting an ignore comment directly above the line with the error. I am not sure if I got the comment 100% right, but sth in that direction should disable the error.

```
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/consistent-type-imports
// @ts-ignore
```

Otherwise, you can also use the import syntax of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75952668/6710876) or adjust your eslint config accordingly.

Btw, I assume `await` is never needed for importing types.

Answer (score 1):

Using `import()` for typing is forbidden by default in the [consistent-type-imports](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/consistent-type-imports) eslint rule, but you can just allow it by setting [`disallowTypeAnnotations`](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/consistent-type-imports/#disallowtypeannotations) to false in your `.eslintrc.json` [rules](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/rules) section:

```json
{
  "rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/consistent-type-imports": ["error", {
      "disallowTypeAnnotations": false
    }],
...
```

Answer (score -1):

It says you MUST import types as

```
import type { Typegen0 } from "./testMachine.server.typegen"
export const machine = createMachine(
    {
      tsTypes: {} as Typegen0,
    ...,
    }
```

You can read more in the documentation: https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/consistent-type-imports/#prefer